# How to accommodate small matter in a slide with appropriate spacing

Tags: fonts

I want my small matter to be included in a separate slide such as to cover the whole slide with appropriate spacing. How can I do it?
Dr. A.S.Muktibodh
India

Comment: What is that small matter? Thank you? Can you post some code with that small content?

Answer (score 1):

As always, the actual execution is more difficult than expected.  Note that all the calculated (expanded) dimensions for trim have to be placed in braces.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\master}
\newsavebox{\zoom}

\savebox{\master}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\lipsum[1]}}% must be outside frame

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Original}
\usebox{\master}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Upper Left}
\adjustbox{scale=2, clip=true, trim=0 {\dimexpr 0.5\ht\master + 0.5\dp\master} {0.5\wd\master} 0}%
  {\usebox{\master}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Upper Right}
\adjustbox{scale=2, clip=true, trim={0.5\wd\master} {\dimexpr 0.5\ht\master + 0.5\dp\master} 0  0}%
  {\usebox{\master}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lower Left}
\adjustbox{scale=2, clip=true, trim=0 0 {0.5\wd\master} {\dimexpr 0.5\ht\master + 0.5\dp\master}}%
  {\usebox{\master}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lower Right}
\adjustbox{scale=2, clip=true, trim={0.5\wd\master} 0 0 {\dimexpr 0.5\ht\master + 0.5\dp\master}}%
  {\usebox{\master}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain what question this is an answer to? I guess that you understood what the OP was asking and are thus able to answer. If so, I think it would be really helpful if you could edit the question to clarify it and make it easier for people with similar issues/desiderata to find. (What is `small matter`? Why is the spacing you've selected more appropriate than other possibilities? I don't get the criteria for success here... ;).

Comment: I assumed he wanted a zoomed in version of the original, or at least part of the original slide.  Anyway, I was bored and it seemed like an interesting problem.

Comment: Oh, I see - sort of. So you think it is something sort of like the spy idea from TikZ but for a whole slide? Thanks, that's helpful. I had no idea that's what was meant.